# script to test auto login website

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, web-application

pardon if i'm ask silly question. I'm newbie in automated testing.

My company re-develop a website with different programming language, but the owner give me task to test which userid and password are correct and can login in previous site, and will import the username and pasword to new system.
the problem is we only have access to previous system just the URL, not the website development server so cannot do anything back there. but i have to ensure that 20.648 rows of username and pasword are correct (i have the data). It's impossible just to think test login manually, then i think of automating login process.

Anyone have solution of this, or if wanna start start from where to learn the automation process,

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

A few tips:

- It sounds like you have the credentials of all your 20'648 customers available *in plain text*. If you do I'd like to know the name of the company so I never ever do business with them.
- If you have a sensible login system the password is hashed and salted, so you **cannot** test an arbitrary user login without an absolutely *giant* amount of computing power to find a collision for the hash. The only way to test such a system is to create a test user in the old system, migrate the data, and test with its credentials on the new system (assuming both systems use the same hashing algorithm, otherwise everybody will have to create new passwords).
- For automated browser testing in general the industry standard is currently [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), which can run tests in any of several languages.

Answer (score 0):

u can start learning selenium

Set selenium properly.

1 - Go to your eclipse.

2 - Go to menu File ->New -> Java project. Give project name like "test" or anything you like.

3 - Click on Next.

4 - Select tab "Libraries" , Select option "Add external JARs"

5 - Add following 3 JARs :

A- selenium-java-2.43.1
  B- selenium-java-2.43.1-srcs
  C- selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0

6 - click on Finish. [Your project creation steps completed here]

7 - Now , Do right click on your project folder and select new->class

8 - Give class name and tick option "public static void main(String[] args]"and click on finish.

Please add below code before your classname in code :

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

After above step , run following sample selenium web driver code to open site :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Read some good selenium tutorial or visit selenium official site. Hope above will help you better.